# Is there a SubItems property in the Metro ListView?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

When I was programming in WinForms, I used ListView control and each `ListViewItem` had `SubItems` property, which was simply usable for inclusion. Does anybody know how can I do it with metro style apps? I was searching in API but I haven't found anything helpful. There isn't any `SubItems` or `Items` property.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there's no such thing, and in my opinion it violates the MVVM pattern. However, in your Model you can provide the appropriate properties and bind to them in your Listview's ItemsTemplate. 
If your trying to build something like a DataGrid, then I'm afraid there's no easy way of doing this in Metro:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/winappswithcsharp/thread/9cf76420-228a-4ff4-8053-75c5b65ccaea